# Error on Insert

Tags: database, delphi, input, delphi-7

I build a project for pos selling.

I use a combobox to show item from db, I use the code

```
  ComboBox1.Items.Clear;
  while not Zpem1.Eof do
  begin
    combobox1.Items.Add(Zpem1.fieldbyname('nama').AsString);
    Zpem1.Next;
  end;
```

and I try to input to cart using

```
begin
con;
  Zpem4.Close;
  Zpem4.SQL.Clear;
  Zpem4.SQL.Add('insert into cart (service,jumlah) values ('+QuotedStr(ComboBox1.text)+','+Edit5.Text+')');
  Zpem4.Open;
```

I'm getting the error message

> current provider are not support returning multiple recordset from single execution

I tried a couple of code, I search from google and still came with the same result

Comment: Did you try `Zpem4.ExecSQL;`not knowing what kind of components you are using.

Comment: To me the error message is misleading and I guess the internal checking is `if ReturnedRecordSetsCount <> 1 then raise ...`. But `INSERT` does not return any recordset and so this exception is raised

Comment: Did you try `Zpem4.Append; Zpem4.FieldByName('service').AsString := 'foo'; Zpem4.FieldByName('jumlah').AsString := 'bar'; Zpem4.Post;`?

Comment: i used zeos connectuion, okay i'll try, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume **zpem4** and **zpem1** both use the same connection?

You'll need to close **zpem1** before using **zpem4**

A provider is the code that allows your Delphi code to interact with the SQL database.   Depending on how the provider is designed, it might not allow you to have two record sets open at the same time.  If you first chunk of code, you open ZPEM1 to populate the Combo box.    In the second code, you are opening ZPEM4 to do the update.   Both create record sets, and the provide only allows one..

Comment: mhhh, why? Could you elaborate.

Comment: ive try using 1 connection, and ive try using 2 connection each zpem1 and zpem4 but still same error